# click handler not working in content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have the following code being run via chrome extension content script. I can't get the click handler to work though. Via the run_at flag in manifest.json the script is being run at document_end. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var enabled = true;

  $('body').append("<button id='#alarmButton'>Disable Alarm</button>");

  $('#alarmButton').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    if (enabled == true) {
      enabled = false;
      $('#alarmButton').text('Enable Alarm');
    } else {
      enabled = true;
      $('#alarmButton').text('Disable Alarm');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try to use `$('body').on('click', '#alarmButton', function () {})`

Comment: I actually did try that after stumbling upon a similar question on here, and unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add `#` in your id attribute.

Change

```
$('body').append("<button id='#alarmButton'>Disable Alarm</button>");
```

to

```
$('body').append("<button id='alarmButton'>Disable Alarm</button>");
```

and for click event use:

```
$('body').on('click', '#alarmButton', function () {})
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8sgxc7o/)

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that. Works beautifully, Thank you. Making me wait 2 minutes to accept the answer, Get it in a few for ya.

Answer (score -2):

You can bind the click event to the button, on create time, before appending to the document. This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var enabled = true;    
  $("<button id='#alarmButton'>Disable Alarm</button>")
    .appendTo('body')
    .click(function() {
      console.log('clicked');
      if (enabled == true) {
        enabled = false;
        $('#alarmButton').text('Enable Alarm');
      } else {
        enabled = true;
        $('#alarmButton').text('Disable Alarm');
      }
    });
});
```